# Where to add httpRuntime in app.config to increase HttpClient request timeout for console application?

Tags: .net, console-application, httpclient, app-config

I am consuming different `web api` from console application through `HttpClient`. It works fine if processing done and response return from `web api` within 1 minute. But if it run more than that then it throw below exception:

> exception: One or more errors occurred.   "System.AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()

I set timeout through code by setting `Timeout` property of `HttpClient` then that works fine. But the problem is I need to do this at each place where I have used `HttpClient` call. I don't want to update this change at everywhere rather I need global configuration to apply for all request.

Below is the code I am using to call `web api` and waiting for response:

```
bool result = false;

System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
//client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); 
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:63303/api/DayRollOver/RunTasks", null).Result;
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processed Successfully");
    result = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"failed. StatusCode: { ((System.Net.HttpStatusCode)httpResponse.StatusCode).ToString() }");
}

Console.WriteLine($"Result: { result }");
```

I am trying to add `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />` in app.config but it not solving problem

Comment: What about create Factory for `HttpClient` and there setup `Timeout` - then anytime you need client - just use factory. Note you using

Comment: @Vladimir, We don't have use Factory and not wanted to use(as it turns into lot of changes in existing application). Can't we just use said element `httpRuntime` in app.config?

Comment: `httpRuntime executionTimeout` is IIS setting typical for `ASP.NET` - so that make no sense for standalone console. Go for Factory.